# Unit Testing win form validation method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Im trying to create some unit tests for CoordinateValidation, but it requires some controls being passed into it. I've tried doing MVC (still new to it) and I dont think I've done a good job, as if I had I wouldn't have to pass in controls?

Is the problem that I have not done MVC correctly or that Im just missing something?

Heres my method im trying to test and the actual unit test:

```
private static bool ValidRange(TextBox tb)
        {
            float x = float.Parse(tb.Text.Split(',')[0]);
            float y = float.Parse(tb.Text.Split(',')[1]);

            if ((x < 10 || x > 1000) || (y < 10 || y > 730))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

public static bool CoordinateValidation(Panel pointsPanel, ErrorProvider errorProvider)
        {
            bool status = true;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^((\d+\.?\d*),{1}(\d+\.?\d*))$");

            foreach (TextBox tb in pointsPanel.Controls)
            {
                Match match = regex.Match(tb.Text);

                if (!match.Success)
                {
                    errorProvider.SetError(tb, "Invalid coordinates!");
                    status = false;
                }

                else if (!ValidRange(tb))
                {
                    errorProvider.SetError(tb, "Invalid range!");
                    status = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    errorProvider.SetError(tb, "");
                }
            }
            return status;
        }

namespace BezierLibrary.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BezierHelperTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CoordinateValidation_InvalidCoordinate_ReturnFalse()
        {
            //Arrange
            var panel = new Panel();
            var textbox = new TextBox();
            var errorProvider = new ErrorProvider();
            panel.Controls.Add(textbox);
            textbox.Text = "5";

            //Act
            var result = BezierHelper.CoordinateValidation(panel, errorProvider);

            //Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ValidRange(TextBox tb) pass just text? CoordinateValidation instead of passing panel with controls as a validator just validate text that will be passed from textbox? Form will have that function to get all textboxes from panel and will be just passing text to validation.  That will give you two simple validation functions , easy to unit test.

Comment: How can I validate the text without first passing the text as an argument? The validate method is in a seperate file, so i need to pass it via an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Leszek Repie says in his comment you should not be passing controls.  Never mix the presentation layer (display/controls) with the business layer (the calculations).  So, when the user clicks on the ok button, in your OkButtonClick handler you extract the text from your textbox.  You then pass this text as a parameter to your business functions.  This also has the benefit of making your unit tests much simpler - you just hard code the test string.

Consider using functions of this form :

```
bool CoordinateValidation(String coordinates, ref String errorMessage    )

bool ValidRange( String coordinates )
```

When you get that working turn your attention to CoordinateValidation().  It does some validation of its own ( validates coordinates ), then calls ValidateRange().  I suggest extracting the validation of the coordinates and placing that code in a new function.  Your CoordinateValidation function then merely calls your new function and ValidateRange().

Hope that helps.

Edit - Here's a little example :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            List<DataTransferObject> dtos = new List<DataTransferObject>();
            dtos.Add( new DataTransferObject() { Field = FieldId.FieldA, Text = textBox1.Text } );
            dtos.Add( new DataTransferObject() { Field = FieldId.FieldB, Text = textBox2.Text } );

            BusinessThing businessThing = new BusinessThing();
            businessThing.Validate( dtos );

            foreach( var dto in dtos )
            {
                if( dto.Error != null )
                {
                    if( dto.Field == FieldId.FieldA )
                    {
                        label1.Text = dto.Error;
                    }
                    // etc
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public enum FieldId
    {
        FieldA,
        FieldB
    }

    public class DataTransferObject
    {
        public FieldId Field { get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
        public String Error { get; set; } = null;
    }

    public class BusinessThing
    {
        private Regex regex = new Regex(@"^((\d+\.?\d*),{1}(\d+\.?\d*))$");

        public void Validate( List<DataTransferObject> dtos )
        {
            foreach( var dto in dtos )
            {
                Validate( dto );
            }
        }

        public void Validate( DataTransferObject dto )
        {
            if( ValidateCoordonate( dto ) )
            {
                ValidateRange( dto );
            }
        }

        public Boolean ValidateCoordonate( DataTransferObject dto )
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(dto.Text);

            if( match.Success )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                dto.Error = "Invalid coordinates!";
                return false;
            }
        }


        public Boolean ValidateRange( DataTransferObject dto )
        {
            float x = float.Parse(dto.Text.Split(',')[0]);
            float y = float.Parse(dto.Text.Split(',')[1]);

            if( (x < 10 || x > 1000) || (y < 10 || y > 730) )
            {
                dto.Error = "Invalid range!";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this helps a lot, one question though, is for the error provider how would it know which text box i am referring to as with using the string errorMessage, theres no way of knowing which text box it is referring to?

Comment: You would need to provide your own way and again pass it in a parameter.  I would suggest an enum.  You can either pass the enum as a second parameter, or create a little data class containing just the string and the enum.  The easiest is probably an additional parameter.   I personally would use the little class.  If you want to validate multiple textboxes at the same time you could pass a list of these little objects.  You could add the return error message to the class too.  It would be the OkButtonClick handler that reported the errors after validation.

Comment: The objective of the separation of presentation and business means that you can later replace your TextBoxes with another type of control, and the only code you need to update id the OkButtonClick handler that is effecting the liaison presentation/business.  The business code remains the same.  The unit tests remain the same.

Comment: I've just added an example